# Is there a Java IDE that has the ability to produce an imagemap?

Tags: java, ide, image-map

Fireworks and Gimp have the ability to produce an image map and HTML code export, but is there a Java IDE that has this ability? Specifically, import an image, draw hotspot shapes with a mouse on the image, associate events with the hotspots, and generate the code?

Comment: You mean java on a webserver using xhtml/tomcat or glassfish? Or like in a window of a JavaFX application?  Via web, most browser send a X/Y coordinate with the POST when an input type=image is used for submitting a form... and I think the ImageView class reports an X/Y of where the click occured as well...

Comment: Preferably for standalone Java application - say Swing, for web, I'd just use Gimp or Fireworks.